# AngularJS e ui-router: carregamento de rotas

Tags: angularjs, front-end, ui-router

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com AngujarJS e ui-router e estou tendo problema no carregamento das rotas.
Para facilitar a explicação vou suprimir partes do código.
Meu arquivo de rotas está assim:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
  controller  : 'DashController'
})
.state('dashboard.vendas', {
  url: '/vendas',
  templateUrl : 'pages/vendas.html',
  controller  : 'vendasController'
})
;

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
      });
});
```

Carrego essa rota **/dashboard** após o login do usuário. Nessa rota, carrego, dentre outras coisas, um método http que retorna as empresas que o usuário terá acesso, através da factory abaixo:

```
app.factory("factoryEmpresas", function($http,urlBase,isAuthenticated) {
return {
    getEmpresas: function() {
        return $http({
            url: urlBase.getUrl() + '/empresas',
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'X-Token': isAuthenticated.getJWT()
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {   
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });

    }
}
});
```

Ao acessar a rota **/vendas** (que é relativa ao state dashboard.vendas), faço outra chamada http utilizando uma variável que está no retorno da **factoryEmpresas** da seguinte forma:

```
app.factory("factoryVendas", function($http,urlBase,isAuthenticated) {
return {
    getVendas: function(id_empresa) {
        return $http({
            url: urlBase.getUrl() + '/vendas?id_empresa=' + id_empresa,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'X-Token': isAuthenticated.getJWT()
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {   
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, até o usuário resolver dar um refresh (F5) quando está na rota **/vendas**. Nesse momento é disparado o carregamento das duas rotas **/dashboad** e **/vendas**. No entanto, ao fazer a chamada http na **factoryVendas**, a **factoryDashboard** ainda não teve o retorno da função getEmpresas. Assim, a variável "id_empresa" não está preenchida com o valor que deveria, resultando assim numa chamada com undefined no lugar do **"id_empresa"**.

A pergunta que faço é, como fazer com que a **factoryVendas** aguarde o retorno da **factoryDashboard** para assim fazer a chamada com a variavel devidamente preenchida?

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a resposta no fórum stackoverflow em inglês.
A solução para esse problema é usar a tag resolve no arquivo de rotas, dessa forma:

```
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
  controller  : 'DashController',
  resolve: {
      Empresas: function(factoryEmpresas) {
          return factoryEmpresas.getEmpresas();
      }
  }
})
.state('dashboard.vendas', {
  url: '/vendas',
  templateUrl : 'pages/vendas.html',
  controller  : 'vendasController',
  resolve: {
      Vendas: function(Empresas, factoryVendas) {
          var id_empresa = Empresas[0].id; // just kind of guessing here
          return factoryVendas.getVendas(id_empresa);
      }
  }
})
```

Assim, a rota dashboard.vendas só irá ser carregada após o carregamento da rota dashboard e a variável id_empresa pode ser carregada da forma correta.